# How to check corresponding parent and child columns to be marked with x?

Tags: excel, powerquery, hierarchy

I've got a data table source, with various columns that could be either x or null. Depending on a hierarchy table, I would like to check the source whether it is filled out correctly, and if not maybe list the child to parent path where the data is incorrect.

The rule / check to be valid would be: if a child is x, all parents have to be x if a parent is x at least one child has to be x

I hope somebody is able to figure out, what I would like to achieve.

```
    source = Table.FromRecords({
        [Name="Jason", A="x", B="x", C="x", D="x", E="x", F="x", G=null, H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L="x", M=null],
        [Name="Joe", A="x", B=null, C="x", D=null, E=null, F=null, G="x", H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M="x"],
        [Name="Eddie", A="x", B=null, C="x", D=null, E=null, F="x", G=null, H="x", I=null, J="x", K=null, L=null, M=null],
        [Name="Phil", A=null, B=null, C=null, D="x", E=null, F=null, G=null, H=null, I=null, J=null, K=null, L="x", M=null],
        [Name="Thomas", A="x", B=null, C=null, D=null, E=null, F="x", G="x", H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
        [Name="David", A="x", B=null, C=null, D=null, E="x", F="x", G=null, H=null, I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
        [Name="Matthew", A=null, B="x", C=null, D=null, E=null, F=null, G=null, H=null, I=null, J=null, K="x", L=null, M=null]
    }),

    hierarchy = Table.FromRecords({
        [Column1 = "A", Hierarchy = {null}],
        [Column1 = "B", Hierarchy = {"A"}],
        [Column1 = "C", Hierarchy = {"A"}],
        [Column1 = "D", Hierarchy = {"A", "C"}],
        [Column1 = "E", Hierarchy = {"A", "C"}],
        [Column1 = "F", Hierarchy = {"A"}],
        [Column1 = "G", Hierarchy = {"A", "F"}],
        [Column1 = "H", Hierarchy = {"A", "F"}],
        [Column1 = "I", Hierarchy = {null}],
        [Column1 = "J", Hierarchy = {"I"}],
        [Column1 = "K", Hierarchy = {"I"}],
        [Column1 = "L", Hierarchy = {"I", "K"}],
        [Column1 = "M", Hierarchy = {"I", "K"}]
    }),
```

Here is a screenshot of some manual comparison:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyCfi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was fun for once, assuming this works

(Updated Phil code input to match image)

[image]

```
let source = Table.FromRecords({
    [Name="Jason", A="x", B="x", C="x", D="x", E="x", F="x", G=null, H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L="x", M=null],
    [Name="Joe", A="x", B=null, C="x", D=null, E=null, F=null, G="x", H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M="x"],
    [Name="Eddie", A="x", B=null, C="x", D=null, E=null, F="x", G=null, H="x", I=null, J="x", K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="Phil", A=null, B=null, C=null, D="x", E=null, F=null, G=null, H=null, I="x", J=null, K="x", L="x", M=null],
    [Name="Thomas", A="x", B=null, C=null, D=null, E=null, F="x", G="x", H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="David", A="x", B=null, C=null, D=null, E="x", F="x", G=null, H=null, I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="Matthew", A=null, B="x", C=null, D=null, E=null, F=null, G=null, H=null, I=null, J=null, K="x", L=null, M=null]
}),

hierarchy = Table.FromRecords({
    [Column1 = "A", Hierarchy = {null}],
    [Column1 = "B", Hierarchy = {"A"}],
    [Column1 = "C", Hierarchy = {"A"}],
    [Column1 = "D", Hierarchy = {"A", "C"}],
    [Column1 = "E", Hierarchy = {"A", "C"}],
    [Column1 = "F", Hierarchy = {"A"}],
    [Column1 = "G", Hierarchy = {"A", "F"}],
    [Column1 = "H", Hierarchy = {"A", "F"}],
    [Column1 = "I", Hierarchy = {null}],
    [Column1 = "J", Hierarchy = {"I"}],
    [Column1 = "K", Hierarchy = {"I"}],
    [Column1 = "L", Hierarchy = {"I", "K"}],
    [Column1 = "M", Hierarchy = {"I", "K"}]
}),

#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(source, {"Name"}, "Attribute","Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Name"}, {{"data", each 
   let a = Table.NestedJoin(_, {"Attribute"}, hierarchy, {"Column1"}, "hierarchy", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    b = Table.ExpandTableColumn(a,"hierarchy", {"Hierarchy"}, {"David"}),
    c = Table.ExpandListColumn(b, "David"),
    d = Table.NestedJoin(c, {"David"}, c, {"Attribute"}, "Ron", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    e = Table.ExpandTableColumn(d, "Ron", {"Attribute"}, {"Peter"}),
    f = Table.SelectRows(e, each ([David] <> null) and ([Peter] = null)),
    g= Table.Group(f, {"Name","Attribute"}, {{"Concat", each Text.Combine([David],","), type text}}),
    h = Table.AddColumn(g, "Custom", each [Attribute]&"->"&[Concat],type text),
    i= try Table.Group( h, {"Name"}, {{"Concat", each Text.Combine([Custom],";"), type text}})  {0}[Concat] otherwise null
in i , type text }}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(source, {"Name"},#"Grouped Rows", {"Name"}, "table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "table2", {"data"}, {"Errors"})
in  #"Expanded table2"
```

you could delete last two steps if you just want the error list

[image]

Comment: AWESOME, thanks mate,  first I was a bit confused about the names for your helper / temporary column, but after preparation of my actual data to the model we used for the use case and slightly modifications of the column names in your code, everything seems to work nicely on first look.

Will check data and results furthermore.   THANKS again :-)   

Yeah sorry you were responding quicker to my previous comment than me rethinking and re-reading your code properly,  sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling currently to fix / implement the following scenario in the provided code:

[same hierarchy, but data sample with parent without childs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q7fE.png)

hierarchy is the initial one from posts above.
data source is changed to:

```
let
    source = Table.FromRecords({
    [Name="Jason", A="x", B="x", C="x", D="x", E="x", F="x", G=null, H="x", I="x", J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="Joe", A="x", B=null, C="x", D=null, E=null, F=null, G="x", H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M="x"],
    [Name="Eddie", A="x", B=null, C="x", D=null, E=null, F="x", G=null, H="x", I=null, J="x", K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="Phil", A=null, B=null, C=null, D="x", E=null, F=null, G=null, H=null, I="x", J=null, K="x", L="x", M=null],
    [Name="Thomas", A="x", B=null, C=null, D=null, E=null, F="x", G="x", H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="David", A="x", B=null, C=null, D=null, E="x", F="x", G=null, H=null, I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="Matthew", A=null, B="x", C=null, D=null, E=null, F=null, G=null, H=null, I=null, J=null, K="x", L=null, M=null]
})
in
    source
```

The expected result would be to have also an error text for those case where

- a parent is marked with x,
- according to hierarchy it has childs,
- but none of the childs are marked with x.
  --> at least one of the childs is expected to be marked as well.

My first idea was to add additional steps in the #"Grouped Rows" =   but I expect somehow that I am gonne introduce to much steps which might not be needed and thus might be inefficient.

```
    f2 = Table.SelectRows(e, each ([David] = null) and ([Peter] = null)),
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error handling in the direction of parents as well as childs using sample data and an hierarchy table.

Thanks again @horseyride for your solution in the direction of parents, I was able to reuse the structure for my new approach.

following the sample queries:

```
// data_stackoverflow
let
    source = Table.FromRecords({
    [Name="Jason", A="x", B="x", C="x", D="x", E="x", F="x", G=null, H="x", I="x", J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="Joe", A="x", B=null, C="x", D=null, E=null, F=null, G="x", H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M="x"],
    [Name="Eddie", A="x", B=null, C="x", D=null, E=null, F="x", G=null, H="x", I=null, J="x", K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="Phil", A=null, B=null, C=null, D="x", E=null, F=null, G=null, H=null, I="x", J=null, K="x", L="x", M=null],
    [Name="Thomas", A="x", B=null, C=null, D=null, E=null, F="x", G="x", H="x", I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="David", A="x", B=null, C=null, D=null, E="x", F="x", G=null, H=null, I=null, J=null, K=null, L=null, M=null],
    [Name="Matthew", A=null, B="x", C=null, D=null, E=null, F=null, G=null, H=null, I=null, J=null, K="x", L=null, M=null]
})
in
    source

// listHierarchyLevels_stackoverflow
let
    source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8jFUitUBUkYQylgpNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [col = _t]),
    col = source[col]
in
    col

// data_hierarchy_stackoverflow
let
    source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bc67CcAwDATQXVR7ifj/nUBoA+Mu+ycIBa5IIe54cCBmusjpnXvvL8QxeXOPGAwDYgSMKgkkqWSTjMMCWFQqSFVpb2s/73XzjjgMB+IEnCoLZJHIAw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [header = _t, L1 = _t, L2 = _t, L3 = _t])
in
    source

// GetHierarchy_stackoverflow
let
    source = data_hierarchy_stackoverflow,
    HierarchyLevels = listHierarchyLevels_stackoverflow,
    FILTER_HierarchyOnly = Table.SelectRows(source, each Record.Field(_, HierarchyLevels{0}) <> null and Record.Field(_, HierarchyLevels{0}) <> ""),
    AddCol_Parents = Table.AddColumn(FILTER_HierarchyOnly, "Parents", each List.RemoveItems(List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(Record.SelectFields(_, HierarchyLevels))), {_[header]})),
    AddCol_LevelNo = Table.AddColumn(AddCol_Parents, "LevelNo", each List.Count(_[Parents])+1),
    AddCol_Level = Table.AddColumn(AddCol_LevelNo, "Level", each HierarchyLevels{_[LevelNo]-1}),
    AddCol_Childs = Table.AddColumn(AddCol_Level, "Childs", (r1) =>
        Table.SelectRows(AddCol_Level, (r2) => (Record.Field(r2, r1[Level]) = r1[header]) and (r2[LevelNo] = r1[LevelNo]+1))[header])
in
    AddCol_Childs

// output_stackoverflow
let
    source = data_stackoverflow,
    Unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(source, {"Name"}, "Attribute","Value"),
    GroupedRows = Table.Group(Unpivot, {"Name"}, {{"data", each 
        let source = _,
            JOIN_hierarchy = Table.NestedJoin(source, {"Attribute"}, GetHierarchy_stackoverflow, {"header"}, "hierarchy", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
            Expand_hierarchy = let cols = Table.ColumnNames(GetHierarchy_stackoverflow) in Table.ExpandTableColumn(JOIN_hierarchy, "hierarchy", cols, cols),
            AddCol_ErrorsParents = Table.AddColumn(Expand_hierarchy, "ErrorsParents", each let misList = List.RemoveItems(_[Parents], Expand_hierarchy[Attribute]) in if List.Count(misList) > 0 then [Attribute]&"->"&Text.Combine(misList,",") else null),
            AddCol_ErrorsChilds = Table.AddColumn(AddCol_ErrorsParents, "ErrorsChilds", each if List.Count(_[Childs]) = 0 or List.ContainsAny(AddCol_ErrorsParents[Attribute], _[Childs]) then null else [Attribute]&"->("&Text.Combine(_[Childs],"|")&")"),
            AddCol_Error = Table.AddColumn(AddCol_ErrorsChilds, "Errors", each let err = Text.Combine({[ErrorsParents], [ErrorsChilds]}, ",") in if err = "" then null else err),
            Group_ConcatErrors_ByName = Table.Group(AddCol_Error, {"Name"}, {"Concat", each Text.Combine([Errors],";"), type text}),
            drilldown = Group_ConcatErrors_ByName{0}[Concat]
        in
            drilldown, type text }}),
    MergedQueries = Table.NestedJoin(source, {"Name"}, GroupedRows, {"Name"}, "table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandedTable = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergedQueries, "table2", {"data"}, {"Errors"})
in
    ExpandedTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I tried to optimized a little further for readability but mainly having both directions checked

- parents --> all parents must be enabled
- child --> at least one child has to be enabled

I tried to find out how to reduce the access to the source file which is either a 1000x15 table in external Excel or even on the same file as tab.
Preview are working nice and smooth as long as I keep  out of business
`allErrors = Text.Combine(onlyErrors[Errors], ";")`.

main code - check query

```
// Check
let

    source = cache,
    hierarchy = Table.Buffer(GetHierarchy),
    hierarchyHeader = hierarchy[header],
    hierarchyCols = List.Buffer(Table.ColumnNames(hierarchy)),
    
/*
    source = cache,
    hierarchy = GetHierarchy,
    hierarchyHeader = hierarchy[header],
    hierarchyCols = List.Buffer(Table.ColumnNames(hierarchy)),
*/

    AddCol_Error = Table.AddColumn(source, "Errors", each bomFunction(_, hierarchy, hierarchyCols)),

    bomFunction = (bomRow, bHierarchy, bHierarchyCols) =>
        let
            // for each row in table (BOM #)
            xTable = Table.SelectRows(Record.ToTable(bomRow), each [Value] = "x"),
            xTableKey = Table.AddKey(xTable, {"Name"}, true),
            JOIN_hierarchy = Table.NestedJoin(xTable, {"Name"}, bHierarchy, "header", "hierarchy", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
            Expand_hierarchy = Table.ExpandTableColumn(JOIN_hierarchy, "hierarchy", bHierarchyCols, bHierarchyCols),
            xList = List.Buffer(Expand_hierarchy[Name]),
            AddCol_Errors = Table.AddColumn(Expand_hierarchy, "Errors", each xFunction(_, xList)),
            onlyErrors = Table.SelectRows(AddCol_Errors, each [Errors] <> null and [Errors] <> ""),
            
            //Group_ConcatErrors_ByName = Table.Group(AddCol_Error, {colIndex}, {"Concat", each Text.Combine([Errors],";"), type text}),
    

            allErrors = Text.Combine(onlyErrors[Errors], ";")
        in
            allErrors,

    xFunction = (x, xList) =>
        let
            // for each x
            //     check for parents
            misList = List.RemoveItems(x[Parents], xList),
            errorsParents = if List.Count(misList) = 0 then null
                            else x[Name] & "->" & Text.Combine(misList,","),

            //     check for childs
            errorsChilds = if List.Count(x[Childs]) = 0 or List.ContainsAny(xList, x[Childs]) then null
                           else x[Name] & "->(" & Text.Combine(x[Childs],"|") & ")",

            err = Text.Combine({errorsParents, errorsChilds})
        in
            err,

    result = AddCol_Error,
    /*ReorderColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(ExpandedTable,
        List.Combine({
            {"Errors"},
            List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(ExpandedTable), {"Errors"})}))*/
    ReorderColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(result, List.Combine({ {"Errors", "#"}, hierarchyHeader}))
in
    ReorderColumns
```

full code

```
// cache
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tabCheck_preparation"]}[Content]
in
    Source

// Check
let

    source = cache,
    hierarchy = Table.Buffer(GetHierarchy),
    hierarchyHeader = hierarchy[header],
    hierarchyCols = List.Buffer(Table.ColumnNames(hierarchy)),
    
/*
    source = cache,
    hierarchy = GetHierarchy,
    hierarchyHeader = hierarchy[header],
    hierarchyCols = List.Buffer(Table.ColumnNames(hierarchy)),
*/

    AddCol_Error = Table.AddColumn(source, "Errors", each bomFunction(_, hierarchy, hierarchyCols)),

    bomFunction = (bomRow, bHierarchy, bHierarchyCols) =>
        let
            // for each row in table (BOM #)
            xTable = Table.SelectRows(Record.ToTable(bomRow), each [Value] = "x"),
            xTableKey = Table.AddKey(xTable, {"Name"}, true),
            JOIN_hierarchy = Table.NestedJoin(xTable, {"Name"}, bHierarchy, "header", "hierarchy", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
            Expand_hierarchy = Table.ExpandTableColumn(JOIN_hierarchy, "hierarchy", bHierarchyCols, bHierarchyCols),
            xList = List.Buffer(Expand_hierarchy[Name]),
            AddCol_Errors = Table.AddColumn(Expand_hierarchy, "Errors", each xFunction(_, xList)),
            onlyErrors = Table.SelectRows(AddCol_Errors, each [Errors] <> null and [Errors] <> ""),
            
            //Group_ConcatErrors_ByName = Table.Group(AddCol_Error, {colIndex}, {"Concat", each Text.Combine([Errors],";"), type text}),
    

            allErrors = Text.Combine(onlyErrors[Errors], ";")
        in
            allErrors,

    xFunction = (x, xList) =>
        let
            // for each x
            //     check for parents
            misList = List.RemoveItems(x[Parents], xList),
            errorsParents = if List.Count(misList) = 0 then null
                            else x[Name] & "->" & Text.Combine(misList,","),

            //     check for childs
            errorsChilds = if List.Count(x[Childs]) = 0 or List.ContainsAny(xList, x[Childs]) then null
                           else x[Name] & "->(" & Text.Combine(x[Childs],"|") & ")",

            err = Text.Combine({errorsParents, errorsChilds})
        in
            err,

    result = AddCol_Error,
    /*ReorderColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(ExpandedTable,
        List.Combine({
            {"Errors"},
            List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(ExpandedTable), {"Errors"})}))*/
    ReorderColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(result, List.Combine({ {"Errors", "#"}, hierarchyHeader}))
in
    ReorderColumns

// tabHeader
let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tabHeader"]}[Content],
    FILTER_relevantOnly = Table.SelectRows(Quelle, each ([Übernahme] = "ja")),
    Replace_NullBy_Kopfzeile = Table.ReplaceValue(FILTER_relevantOnly,null, each [Kopfzeile], Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"Kopfzeile_Renamed"})
in
    Replace_NullBy_Kopfzeile

// GetHierarchy
let
    Quelle = tabHeader,
    HierarchyLevels = listHierarchyLevels,
    FILTER_HierarchyLevels = Table.SelectRows(Quelle, each List.Contains(HierarchyLevels, [hierarchy])),
    KEEP_HierarchyColumns = Table.SelectColumns(FILTER_HierarchyLevels, List.Combine({{"Kopfzeile_Renamed"}, HierarchyLevels})),
    RenameCol_header = Table.RenameColumns(KEEP_HierarchyColumns,{{"Kopfzeile_Renamed", "header"}}),
    Replace_EmptyBy_Null = Table.ReplaceValue(RenameCol_header,"",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue, listHierarchyLevels),
    AddCol_Parents = Table.AddColumn(Replace_EmptyBy_Null, "Parents", each List.RemoveItems(List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(Record.SelectFields(_, HierarchyLevels))), {_[header]})),
    AddCol_LevelNo = Table.AddColumn(AddCol_Parents, "LevelNo", each List.Count(_[Parents])+1),
    AddCol_Level = Table.AddColumn(AddCol_LevelNo, "Level", each HierarchyLevels{_[LevelNo]-1}),
    #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(AddCol_Level),
    FILTER_maxLevel = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Errors", let maxLevel = List.Count(HierarchyLevels) in each ([LevelNo] <= maxLevel)),
    AddCol_Childs = Table.AddColumn(FILTER_maxLevel, "Childs", (r1) =>
        Table.SelectRows(FILTER_maxLevel, (r2) => (Record.Field(r2, r1[Level]) = r1[header]) and (r2[LevelNo] = r1[LevelNo]+1))[header]),
    RemovedCols_Hierarchy = Table.RemoveColumns(AddCol_Childs, HierarchyLevels)
in
    RemovedCols_Hierarchy

// listHierarchyLevels
let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tabHierarchyLevels"]}[Content],
    FILTER_ja = Table.SelectRows(Quelle, each ([validate] = "ja")),
    listHierarchies = FILTER_ja[listHierarchies]
in
    listHierarchies
```